# Syntax error with SQL in Java

Tags: java, sql

Am I missing something silly here?

```
String update = "UPDATE Patients SET fullName = '" + patient.getName() + "', 
                 houseNum = '" + patient.getHouseNum() + "', 
                 address = '" + patient.getAddress() +"', 
                 postCode = '" + patient.getPostCode() + "', 
                 condition = '" + patient.getCondition() +  "', 
                 who = '" + patient.getWho() + "', 
                 time = '" + patient.getTime() + "', 
                 location = '" + patient.getLocation() + "', 
                 actionTaken = '" + patient.getActionTaken() + "', 
                 duration = '" + patient.getDuration() + "' 
                 WHERE regNo = '" +patient.getNHSnum()+"'";
```

For the sake of it, I returned on each new line for formatting here. Within my file it's on a single line. All database fields are of type text.

The error I get is:

```
[Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Syntax error in UPDATE statement. -3503
```

**EDIT:**

For info, the following works ok:

```
String update = "UPDATE Patients SET fullName = '" + patient.getName() + "', 
                houseNum = '" + patient.getHouseNum() + "', 
                address = '" + patient.getAddress() +"', 
                postCode = '" + patient.getPostCode() + "', 
                condition = '" + patient.getCondition() +  "' 
                WHERE regNo = '" +patient.getNHSnum()+"'";
```

**EDIT2:**

Here is the update string in full:

```
UPDATE Patients SET fullName = 'Dave', houseNum = '5', address = 'Bla', postCode = 'PQ1 RS2', condition = 'Unknown', who = 'Test', time = 'Test1', location = 'Test2', actionTaken = 'Test3', duration = 'Test4' WHERE regNo = '1'
```

As I said, in this example, every field in the database is of type text

Comment: You're missing the fact that you're opening yourself to a SQL injection attack by not using parameters with `PreparedStatement`...

Comment: What is the return types of each of the methods in the `patient` object?

Comment: How does the final query look like? Value of `update`..

Comment: in your date properties, have you confirmed that the string format is YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS or otherwise right for your backend sql implementation? are all your feilds strings? if not drop the '' around each var that isn't.

Comment: try to dump the final query, with all parameters. Maybe is one of the parameters that breaks the statement. Also, you can try the dichotomic search: remove the second half of the query and try. If it works, re-insert the first half of the second half in the string and so on

Comment: @meekel doent your EDIT2 work ??

Comment: Well that's what the original query is and still generates the same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`time` is an SQL reserved word. Best is to rename it, otherwise it is often a vendant dependant quoting, deviating from standard SQL.

Fully agree with the PreparedStatement remarks.

Comment: You my friend, are a legend.

Answer (score 3):

i  would **strongly** recommend you to use [**PreparedStatements**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html), rather than simple Statement (which would lead to SQl injection).

Below is an example of executing an **Update** using PreparedStatement.

```
String query = "UPDATE TABLENAME SET COL1=?, COL2=? WHERE somecondistrue";
Statement st = connection.preparedStatement(query);
st.setString(1, col1value);
st.setString(2, col2Value);
st.executeUpdate();
```

as you can see, this is more **neater approach** of executing **SQL Queries** using **JDBC**.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the commas in number fields like num and duration

Comment: The database fields are all of type text. All methods of Patient return String.

Answer (score 1):

You should use PreparedStatements, since all fields are string type the only problem I could see here is you be passing strings with the character **'**, that would generate an error

Answer (score 0):

As other people said, you should use prepared statements. In fact, consider if one of your patient names had an apostrophe (like O'Brien). Prepared statements would solve that issue.

Hard to say otherwise without seeing the final query.

Answer (score 0):

The issue probably is that some values that you are trying to update contains an apostrophe `'` or other special characters. You can print the `update` string before executing the statement, and see if this is the case. A simple:

```
System.out.println("update: "+update);
```

will help you easily see if you are hitting this issue. 
Also, like other have mentioned, if you will use [PreparedStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) you will not have to worry about SQL-injection issues and will not hit this issue.

Comment: I posted the update string in an edit to the question. Can't see anything noticeably wrong.

Comment: @Meekel And you are getting that error for the `update` string? I used  [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/89734/2) and confirmed that your update is working.